# TfsPublisher logger for dotnet vstest

Tags: .net, .net-core, command-line-interface, vstest, vstest.console.exe

When we use

`"dotnet vstest "Mytest.dll" /logger:TfsPublisher;Collection="<TFSURL>";BuildName="<BuildName>";TeamProject="<Project>";Platform="AnyCPU";Flavor="Release";`

We get the following error:

`Could not find a test logger with AssemblyQualifiedName, URI or FriendlyName 'TfsPublisher'.`

The call works with vstest.console.exe and the same parameters.

The weird thing is the version of vstest.host.exe is *15.7.1*, but dotnet vshost is *15.7.0*.

How can i install the TfsLogger extension for the dotnet CLI interface?